# Understanding the list output

Tags: python

I am trying to test opensource package `paralex - [readme][1]`, I want to see the value of result and score in given function.

Code is:

```
def run_on_question(s, con):
    q = get_sent(s)
    scored_answers = defaultdict(lambda: float('-inf'))
    scored_queries = lex.parse.get_scored_queries(q, con.nl_vocab, con.lexicon, con.weights)
    i = 0
    for score, query in sorted(scored_queries, reverse=True):
        print ' Score : %s  - query :  %s' % ( score, query)
        #print "%s %s " % (score, query) this also gives same result
```

called function is:

```
def get_scored_queries(sent, nl_vocab, lexicon, weights):
    parses = parse(sent, nl_vocab, lexicon)
    scored = list((score_parse(p, weights), p) for p in parses)
    best_scores = defaultdict(lambda: float('-inf'))
    for s, p in scored:
        best_scores[p.meaning] = max(best_scores[p.meaning], s)
    results = list((v,k) for (k,v) in best_scores.iteritems())
    results.sort(reverse=True)
    return results
```

Result looks like:

```
Score : -0.444444444449  - query :  (2, 1, 798848, 660874)
 Score : -0.444444444449  - query :  (2, 1, 787068, 660874)
 Score : -0.444444444449  - query :  (2, 1, 786980, 660874)
 Score : -0.555555555555  - query :  (2, 1, 820915, 589484)
 Score : -0.555555555555  - query :  (2, 1, 798901, 589484)
 Score : -0.666666666667  - query :  (2, 1, 725195, 660811)
 Score : -0.666666666667  - query :  (2, 1, 725195, 660727)
 Score : -0.666666666671  - query :  (2, 1, 708932, 660874)
 Score : -0.777777777777  - query :  (2, 1, 725198, 589484)
 Score : -0.777777777778  - query :  (2, 1, 798848, 2551164)
 Score : -0.777777777778  - query :  (2, 1, 798848, 996458)
 Score : -0.888888888889  - query :  (2, 1, 725196, 589484)
 Score : -0.888888888889  - query :  (2, 1, 708932, 2569298)
 Score : -0.888888888889  - query :  (2, 1, 708932, 2327035)
 Score : -0.888888888889  - query :  (2, 1, 708932, 2036311)
 Score : -1.0  - query :  (2, 1, 880853, 555134)
 Score : -1.0  - query :  (2, 1, 880797, 555134)
 Score : -1.0  - query :  (2, 1, 880794, 555134)
 Score : -1.0  - query :  (2, 1, 880791, 555134)
```

Any idea in what format does this results comes?

Comment: So what are you expecting the output to be ?

Comment: I don't see code *calling*  any of these functions. Where does the input come from?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the sorted output from `scores_queries` printed using formatting:

```
  for score, query in sorted(scored_queries, reverse=True):
        print ' Score : %s  - query :  %s' % ( score, query)
```

`results` is a sorted list from the `best_scores` dict where the first item in each tuple is each value from the dict and the second is each key.

If you want to see results simply put a `print(results)` in the function.

Comment: thanks but printing in that manner also gives result similar i.e. `(2.222222222215, (2, 1, 687896, 1415203)), (2.222222222214, (2, 1, 564349, 1415203)), (2.111111111105, (2, 1, 2348232, 1415203)), (2.111111111105, (2, 1, 842895, 1415203)), (2.111111111105, (2, 1, 755225, 1415203)), (2.111111111105, (2, 1, 747876, 1415203)), (2.111111111105, (2, 1, 689748, 1415203)), (2.111111111105, (2, 1, 689715, 1415203)), (1.9999999999929998, (2, 1, 564338, 1415203)), .....`

Comment: you mean when you print results? results is simply a list of tuples that lex.parse operates on. I would look at the source of lex.parse and that will probably be insightful as to what it does with results

Comment: yes @Padraic still is there any way to see actual result. Score is float value and query is in string

Comment: You can see every thing by just adding prints  like `print(sorted(scored_queries, reverse=True)`, `print(q)` etc..